# Functional programming: does using a generic make a function impure?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, pure-function

```
    public static Func<string, Task<T>> MyMethod<T>(
        UserCredentials credentials,
        Func<string, string, string, Task<T>> func
    ) =>
        async (value) => await func(credentials.user, credentials.pwd, value);
```

I'm having difficulty discerning the purity of the function, because obviously `T(int)` results in a different output as `T(string)`. Or does the purity depend on `T(int) = 5` always resulting in 10 and `T(string)` = "Foo" always resulting in "Bar"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Or does the purity depend on T(int) = 5 always resulting in 10 and T(string) = "Foo" always resulting in "Bar"?

Yes.

A Type Parameter is still one of the function's input parameters, even though it doesn't reside within the function's parentheses.  The definition of a pure function is that, given the same values for its input parameters, it will still produce the same result (without any side-effects).

Comment: That's where I was leaning too, but I'm new to this way of thinking. Thank you.

Comment: Note: purity is not the same as idempotency. idempotency says that `f(f(x) == f(x) FORALL x`, or in other words: the result of executing a subroutine multiple times is the same as executing it once. `sqrt` is pure, but not idempotent: `sqrt(sqrt(16))` is not the same as `sqrt(16)`. Conversely, a subroutine that deletes a particular file is idempotent (if you execute it once, the result is that the file is gone, if you execute it multiple times, the file is still gone) but clearly not pure.

Comment: Your sqrt example doesn't make any sense.  Nobody disagrees that those two calls return a different result, but you're not passing in the same value, are you?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Jörg is using the [mathematical definition of Idempotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) (see the first bullet point in the lead section), not the common software engineering one, which can be seen as equivalent if the state of the system is an additional implicit parameter to the function.

Comment: Yes, I am: I am passing 16 both times. If `sqrt` were idempotent, then the result of `sqrt(16)` and `sqrt(sqrt(16))` should be the same. Your "pure/idempotent" suggests that those two concepts are the same or at least closely related, when in fact, they are orthogonal: I give two examples of functions/subroutines that are pure but not idempotent, and idempotent but not pure. (In fact, the idea of idempotency, at least as commonly applied in programming, isn't very interesting *without* side-effects.) `abs` is an example of a function that is both pure and idempotent.

Comment: ... i.e. if a function `f(x, S) -> (x', S')` is interpreted as accepting parameter `x` with system state on entry of `S`, returning `x'` and modifying the system state to `S'`, then it is idempotent iff `f(f(x,S))` also yields `(x', S')`, which you should be able to see agrees with both Jörg's definition and the usual way of understanding the word in software engineering.

Comment: The most widely-known application of this is HTTP, where `POST` makes no guarantees, `PUT` is guaranteed to be idempotent, and `GET` and `HEAD` are guaranteed to be idempotent and pure, which is extremely important for both caching and reliability (idempotency meaning that I can safely retry an operation without checking whether it had any side-effects or not, purity meaning that I can safely cache an operation, and both meaning that I can safely pre-fetch operations for caching).

Comment: Early web applications often violated those guarantees, by e.g. performing operations such as ordering something from a store or deleting a user account using `GET` requests, which broke in rather serious ways, when "web accelerators" (proxies or browser background processes that transparently pre-fetched links from websites the user was currently browsing) were invented.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm not sure I buy that GET is pure.  Yes, it has no side effects but it can definitely depend on hidden information i.e. the result is not purely (see what I did there) dependent on the input.

Answer (score 3):

Using the definition of [Pure Function from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), a function is pure if:

1. The function always evaluates the same result value given the same argument value(s). The function result value cannot depend on any hidden information or state that may change while program execution proceeds or between different executions of the program, nor can it depend on any external input from I/O devices (usually—see below).
2. Evaluation of the result does not cause any semantically observable side effect or output, such as mutation of mutable objects or output to I/O devices (usually—see below).

There are two ways I think you can look at this: 1. the type parameter T is part of the function definition or it's part of the input to the function.  Either way, I don't think it matters in determining whether the function is pure.